# How to set the default / base collection of a XQJ Connection

Tags: collections, xquery, exist-db

I want to query the eXist db via the XQJ API. Therefore I have an XQuery file which I want to apply to several different documents inside different collections of the database.

My question is, how can I set the path to the document/collection? I want to apply the XQuery only on specific documents/collections and can´t set the path directly in the XQuery document (with the doc('path/to/doc') function ), because I want to apply the same XQuery to several files with different paths.

I could bind a Java variable to an Xquery expression but there has to be a more elegant way to achieve this task with the XQJ API. Hope you can help me out a little bit.

Comment: It seems like  either the XQY is responsible for managing the paths or Java is, in which case you'll need to pass the path as an external variable to XQY. I'm not sure there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the specific document URIs up-front, you could bind a bunch of URIs as a xs:string sequence, where you can then iterate through them in your XQuery expression, performing operations against each URI as necessary.

```
declare variable $uris as xs:string* external;

for $uri in $uris
return (
 (: perform operation against $uri :)
)
```

Or if you know the collection uri,

```
declare variable $collection-uri as xs:string external;

for $document-node in fn:collection($collection-uri)
return (
  (: perform operation against document-node() :)
)
```

In a future version of eXist XQJ API, you will be able to set a collection as the default context, which goes against both the XQJ standard AND the XQuery 1.0 / 3.0 standards but other users appear to be wanting this functionality quite badly.

Comment: OK, thank you guys, then the variable binding it is, hoped I could get around that.